# How to find out if matrix is invertible (regular, nonsingular, full rank...) in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

When computing the inverse of a matrix in **Eigen** [it is up to the user to check if this can be done:](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-2.0/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a5782c3af36c3083685e4df868c201fc5)

> This matrix must be invertible, otherwise the result is undefined.

but how can I check for this condition in **Eigen**?

Comment: You can edit that code into your question if you like, but I am not going to have a code sample in my answer that exemplifies doing the decomposition twice (once to see if inversion is possible, again to invert).  There is a reason that `FullPivLV::isInvertible()` isn't a static member function.  It would be more appropriate to return a `boost::optional` or use the TryXXX pattern which returns a boolean indicating whether inversion is possible, and if it is, fills an output parameter with the inverse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eigen provides a rank-revealing LU decomposition, which provides an [`isInvertible` member function](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html#ab60c7d993c9eba31668fb8886d621094).

See

- [`class Eigen::FullPivLU< MatrixType >`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are [plenty of other properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Properties) of matrices that hold only for invertible matrices. You can check one of those to see if the matrix is invertible.

One possibility is to check if the [determinant](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#ad63cea11a4bf220298dce4489a1704c7) is `0`. Iff so, the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Checking the determinant is not very robust, however, due to inexact floating-point calculations.